# How to detect if player is moving Left/Right/Back/Forward

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My player can only move along straight horizontal and vertical lines. I want to detect whether they are moving left, right, back, or forward at any given point in time. They can rotate any way they like in the game.

I've tried detecting this when users press the arrows keys and then checking if the current player position along the X or Y (z transform) planes is different than it was before. That didn't seem to work.

I also tried using this code from Unity answers where a similar question was asked but it isn't working for me:

```
 float dot = Vector3.Dot(transform.forward, Vector3.forward);
 if(dot > 0.9) // going forward direction
 else if (dot < - 0.9) // going opposite to forward direction
 else{
      Vector3 cross = Vector3.Cross(transform.forward, Vector3.forward);
      // This could be the other way around...never remember which order
      if(cross.y < 0) // going right 
      else // going left 
 }
```

Comment: How isnt it working gor you? Is it because the vector checked against should be different? Example uses forward, maybe it is up. You need to tell more because if you are in 2d then the input shall be enough to indicate direction.

Comment: The game is in 3d.

Comment: Ok, say no more.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to check the velocity if your Character gets moved by Physics. If your Character moves with something where velocity does not fulfill the job, then you would save the last position and check it with the new one like your first idea was.

#### Velocity

So like I said when your Character moves with Physics you could check the direction like this:

```cs
public RigidBody rb; // Add the rigidbody of your Player to your script

void Update() {
    // What ever your code is here
    Vector3 vel = transform.rotation * rb.velocity;
    if(vel.z > 0) {
        // forward
    } else if(vel.z < 0) {
        // backwards
    }
    if(vel.x > 0) {
        // right
    } else if(vel.x < 0) {
        // left
    }
}
```

#### Position

You can also check the movement by position. For this you need to compare not only old Pos and new Pos but also old Rotation and new Rotation.
What I could think of is: 
(Not tested)

```cs
Vector3 oldPos;
Quaternion oldRot;

Update() {
    Vector3 movement = oldRot * (transform.position - oldPos));
    if(movement.z > 0) {
        // forward
    } else if(movement.z < 0) {
        // backwards
    }
    if(movement.x > 0) {
        // right
    } else if(movement.x < 0) {
        // left
    }
    oldPos = transform.position;
    oldRot = transform.rotation;
}
```

Comment: You're multiplying two vectors here: rb.velocity * transform.forward which is most likely to throw ambiguous exception.

Comment: @merkithuseyin ah yeah sry. I was a little bit brain dead in that moment. Obviously it should get multiplyed by the rotation

Comment: ANother way would also be useing `float xVel = transform.InverseTransformDirection(rigidbody.velocity).x;` as mentioned in this Forum: https://answers.unity.com/questions/32551/how-do-i-obtain-the-local-velocity-of-a-rigid-body.html

Comment: @AtLeastVision and who tells you OP is using `Rigidbody` ...?

Comment: @derHugo Did you read my whole post? My 2nd sentence already says that this is the way with rb. If he does not use velocity then he has to do the same thing with position which may be a  bit more complicated.